# How to convert contents of DBObject to a string?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

Printing the DBObject through following code:

```
DBObject theObj = cursor.next();
System.out.println(theObj);
```

Output:

```
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "58b94b7bcd4b42b0b5e8c7c2"} , "content" : "<p><del class=\"ice-del ice-cts\" data-changedata=\"\" data-cid=\"2\" data-last-change-time=\"1488543686518\" data-time=\"1488543686518\" data-userid=\"\" data-username=\"\">Old content</del></p>\r\n"}
```

Now, consider the following variable

`String content;`

I need the value of the string variable content to be content field value in the database 
`"<p><del class=\"ice-del ice-cts\" data-changedata=\"\" data-cid=\"2\" data-last-change-time=\"1488543686518\" data-time=\"1488543686518\" data-userid=\"\" data-username=\"\">Old content</del></p>\r\n"`

How to do that? I am not able to find googling.

Comment: Did you take a look at the methods of ``DBObject``?

Comment: Just go through all getter methods of DBObject class and retrieve appropriate content you want to append into your content string

Comment: Please read the java docs for the DBObject class. http://api.mongodb.com/java/2.0/org/bson/BasicBSONObject.html#getString(java.lang.String)

Comment: Thanks for the comments and links. I gone through the methods of DBObject and found the answer. I have answered my own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
DBObject theObj = cursor.next();
String contentString =  theObj.getString("content");
System.out.println(contentString);
```

Output:

```
<p><del class="ice-del ice-cts" data-changedata="" data-cid="2" data-last-change-time="1488543686518" data-time="1488543686518" data-userid="" data-username="">Old content</del></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that this should be more efficient, and I'm pretty sure that is gonna work:

```
DBObject theObj = cursor.next();
String result = theObj.toString();
System.out.println(result);
```